# ngApp doesn't initialize AngularJS app, but ng-app does

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I had thought that there was absolutely no difference between using the various forms of Angular directive names, e.g., ngApp, ng-app, x-ng-app should all be interchangeable.

But on this page, Angular doesn't initialize if I use 'ngApp', while everything works fine if I use 'ng-app.' Anyone know why?

```
<html ngApp> <!-- works if 'ng-app' -->
  <head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller='MainController'>
        {{alive}}
    </div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function MainController($scope) {
      $scope.alive = "I'm alive!";
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: As noted in the answer below angular does a conversion when looking at the HTML and trying to find directives, it converts any of the forms data-ng-model ng-model x-data-ng-model into ngModel which is how it would be defined in the JS.  I think the problem is people do not generally consider HTML attributes to be case sensitive hence the difference.  Anywhere you see an upper case letter in the directive name it should just be preceded by a hyphen when used in HTML (common gotcha when writing your own).

Comment: Also worth noting that Angular will ignore data prefixes. So data-ng-app will be the same as ng-app. This means you can't call a directive data-check for instance as it will normalise to 'check'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For angular directives, you need to use the lowercase hyphenated version when referencing them in your html markup and the lower-camelcase version when you reference them in your JavaScript code.

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine
>   which elements match which directives. We typically refer to
>   directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g.
>   ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).